# NMR calculations with NWChem quantum chemistry program

Tags: computational-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, software

I tried experimenting with some *ab initio* NMR calculations using the NWChem program. I used quinuclidine as a simple test case. The input file was:

```
echo
start quinuclidine_b3ylp_opt_nmr_shift

geometry
  c         -6.06576        0.97412       -0.15301
  c         -5.70979        1.98552       -1.28158
  c         -4.36490        2.65888       -0.91745
  h         -6.47615        2.78876       -1.35616
  h         -5.68491        1.45114       -2.25601
  c         -3.37563        1.54341       -0.50314
  c         -3.86410        0.94013        0.84625
  h         -2.33065        1.90335       -0.38494
  h         -3.37977        0.77674       -1.30967
  n         -5.29417        1.27496        1.08291
  h         -3.26800        1.37762        1.67961
  h         -3.67643       -0.15484        0.87417
  h         -5.79345       -0.05430       -0.48418
  h         -7.16227        0.96043        0.02635
  c         -5.40220        2.73070        1.37047
  c         -4.60680        3.55788        0.31857
  h         -5.06760        2.98401        2.39936
  h         -6.47931        3.01065        1.31755
  h         -3.96835        3.24945       -1.77113
  h         -3.61077        3.85719        0.71410
  h         -5.16983        4.48719        0.08363
end

basis
 * library 6-311G
end

dft
 xc b3lyp
end

title "Quinuclidine B3LYP/6-311G geom opt nmr shift"
task dft optimize

basis
 * library 6-311G
end
dft
 xc b3lyp
end

property
 gshift
 shielding
end

task dft property
```

Next, I calculated the chemical shift of the TMS standard:

```
echo
start tms_b3lyp_opt_freq_nmr_shift

geometry units angstroms
  si  -5.37335102864362      2.43869139121700     -0.00017138545369
  c   -3.50689688966580      2.43868715601638     -0.00001133876668
  c   -5.99529466705065      4.19430001974021      0.12209335653192
  h   -5.64408778702798      4.67985919142380      1.04819971762123
  h   -7.09781476514675      4.22936546250064      0.12467467866764
  h   -5.64435465416627      4.80382888763710     -0.72767673129762
  h   -3.10677010278341      2.89237170000804      0.92240456642084
  h   -3.10633327621776      3.01074016686707     -0.85387463583008
  h   -3.10622471891726      1.41321522592654     -0.06819713587793
  c   -5.99568159818493      1.45555000740651      1.45925444723856
  c   -5.99571944212990      1.66683194553091     -1.58150765777166
  h   -5.64537419258706      1.88774171172852      2.41177722402156
  h   -5.64408400205021      0.41082962309567      1.41778721376507
  h   -7.09821437068132      1.43547142531899      1.48770835119311
  h   -5.64584598058862      2.22683552653798     -2.46512226305553
  h   -7.09824537965055      1.65038972286304     -1.61218398701376
  h   -5.64368714450789      0.62658083618162     -1.68513442039297
end

basis
 * library 6-311G
end

dft
 xc b3lyp
end

title "TMS VWN5/aug-cc-pVDZ geom opt nmr shift"
task dft optimize

basis
 * library 6-311G
end
dft
 xc b3lyp
end

property
 gshift
 shielding
end

task dft property
```

However, the resulting chemical shifts are **terribly** off from the experimental ones. Am I doing an obvious mistake or is the big deviation just the best you can get out of such calculations? What is your experience and approach to *ab initio* NMR calculations (i.e. chemical shifts and coupling constants)?

Comment: I also tried out calculation chemical shifts/coupling constants with ORCA. However, in all the simple test cases I tried out, I always got **huge deviations** from experiment. This is why I am unsure now if I make an obvious mistake, e.g. not using a solvent model or if those calculations just are that unprecise. I somehow feel that just not handling solvent or using an appropriately sized basis set should **completely screw up** the results of such calculations.

Comment: I know of some cases (such as Pt NMR) where the absolute isotropic shielding constant is EXTREMELY sensitive to the geometry (a deviation of 0.01 Angstroms can lead to a change in this value by a couple hundred ppm or more).  However, you can sometimes get good error cancellation with your reference compound.  Also, try considering solvent in your calculations (COSMO, PCM, etc.) though your mileage may vary.

Comment: It is hard to discern what exactly went wrong without a peak at the output files. Did you scale the values output? See this site for more information: http://cheshirenmr.info/index.htm

Comment: Can you  upload (or http://pastebin.com/ ) the relevant section of the outputs. I am curious about how they look like. I've never used NWChem nor Orca for chemical shift calculations. Thanks in advance.
Also, notice that it can be important in order to answer your question.

Comment: @user1420303 I will do that ASAP.

Comment: Before I make an attempt at a full answer, can you post more information about the experimental values, or at least a reference? Also, don't use ORCA for NMR, that part of the program doesn't give the correct answers.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Don't use ORCA for NMR, that part of the program doesn't give the correct answers. What do you mean by that? Somewhere in ORCAs only documentation I also found the note that ORCA shouldn't be used for NMR calculations as "IGLO is outdated" and "should only be used by expert users". However the ORCA manual doesn't say anything like this. The experimental values can be found for example at the SDBS spectra database.

Comment: @deusexmachina As a former ORCA developer, I am interested in (and dispute) the claim about the EPR/NMR module of ORCA. Can you give evidence? It should also be noted that with the recent 4.0 release, a "GIAO implementation for NMR chemical shifts" was made available.

Comment: @TAR86 I found this statement in the online ORCA documentation -- so maybe it is outdated. Thanks for pointing out that ORCA 4.0 now includes a GIAO implementation I guess I will try out at some point in time. Really, I tried NMR chemical shift calculations *a lot* and always got very bad results out of them, as soon as I have some time on my hands I will make a more sophisticated study on how ORCA/NWChem/Gaussian NMR calculations perform on some simple test systems, where reference data are available. But thanks for all the input : )

Answer (score 3):

Those calculations are tricky because some functionals work well, others don't, some basis sets work well while even a better basis might give bad results and so on.

We did some studies in the past using the GIAO Method in G09 with B3LYP and 6-311+G(2d,p) als basis for the NMR calculations and M06-2X/6-311++G(d,p)for geometry optimization. And that worked quite well. However, we always used solvated systems (PCM) which seems to be the common way to do it. Try to reoptimize in solvent and run the NMR calculation in solvent if that's possible in NWChem.

Comment: I will perform the calculations with a solvent model and see if it gets better. Thanks : )

Comment: While I may lack specific experience in the calculation of chemical shifts, it is immediately apparent that "general purpose" and frankly outdated basis sets of the Pople variety such as 6-311G... are not a good choice. Things may improve if the basis set is (partially) decontracted (to give sufficient variational freedom at the nuclei) - but then one gives up any advantage of the small basis set and may use a better one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I use Gaussian 09 to obtain NMR $\ce{^{13}C}$ chemical shifts (cs) with great accuracy. The best results are obtain if the calculated cs are scaled. So, I recommend to use this level of theory:

1. Opt => mPW1PW91/6-31G(d)  with tight criteria (`opt=tight`)
2. NNR => mPW1PW91/6-31G(d)  with `nmr int=ultafine`
3. To scale: $\text{scaled cs} = \text{(calculated cs)}*1.05 - 1.22$ ([See reference](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Fernando_Martins_Dos_Santos_Junior/publication/259077748_High_cost-effectiveness_ratio_GIAO-MPW1PW91_6-31GdMPW1PW916-31Gd_scaling_factor_for_13C_nuclear_magnetic_resonance_chemical_shifts_calculation/links/555a3b8108ae6943a877cc03.pdf))

Answer (score -1):

here I have one example: https://github.com/miroi/open-collection/tree/master/theoretical_chemistry/projects/nmr_diplomovky/derivaty_markerov/derivative_2_Peter/nwchem

where geometry optimization was performed with "classic" basis  6-311++g2d_2p, but NMR parameters were computed with the decontracted NMR-DKH_TZ2P basis set. We used several DFT functionals. Plus cosmo solvent effects. Try this combination.